# How can I apply changes of a forked repository?

Tags: git, version-control, github

I have just started working with github. I created a new repository. Someone else have forked my repository. I want to know how can I apply his commits on the original repository.

Comment: Duplicate of http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148003/pulling-in-changes-from-a-forked-repo-without-a-request-on-github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm agreed that it's duplicate but answer there is a bit overhead...

you can just `git pull <fork_repository_address> <fork_branch>`